# How to convert takerRate to readable value from 1inch API OrderBook?

Tags: web3js, javascript, bignumber, decimals, convert

I use 1inch API to get a list of order limits by the specific token.
https://portal.1inch.dev/documentation/orderbook/introduction

pair **AXL/axlUSDC**

and I get a response something like that:

```
[
  {
        "signature": "0x9d6bb06d2c5d8f733991ee01beb7afff5257918fd961f8a6a3fd4d0e367704fb1ee8b0979b3b5be06d838791d68111efda1bcdb3cffb1d9819bb4762eaa20e7b1c",
        "orderHash": "0xd490cb6908363b3468f81c91d81843b04a176f80ead40881d1988d08d287cd00",
        "createDateTime": "2024-03-12T09:53:39.760Z",
        "remainingMakerAmount": "2788000000000000000000",
        "makerBalance": "3327469248075000000000",
        "makerAllowance": "1000000000000000000000000",
        "data": {
          "makerAsset": "0xda10009cbd5d07dd0cecc66161fc93d7c9000da1",
          "takerAsset": "0x23ee2343b892b1bb63503a4fabc840e0e2c6810f",
          "salt": "13537334990369695199770995521817395556492318714327132363228881831712558524628",
          "receiver": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
          "makingAmount": "2788000000000000000000",
          "takingAmount": "7744444444",
          "maker": "0x29ed2d47a4a80dcc44a91ff69a376ddbabd64ebd",
          "extension": "0x",
          "makerTraits": "0x4400000000000000000000000000000000006617b2fb00000000000000000000"
        },
        "makerRate": "0.000000000002777778",
        "takerRate": "360000000020.659971306781060046",
        "isMakerContract": false,
        "orderInvalidReason": null
      }
    ]
```

I don't understand how to properly transform not readable ***takerRate/makerRate*** to readable. Probably, I should use BigNumber.js and tokens decimals, but I don't get it((.
Obviously, "360000000020.659971306781060046" is not correct USD (axlUSDC, USDC, etc) value.

Can you help me guys? Thanks!